# Where is my mistake in evaluating $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

Given is $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x}$

I divide numerator and denominator by x to the largest degree in the denominator and I get
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x^2}}}{1}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{1}=1.$$
But the answer should be -1. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Dividing by negative $x$, check the sign of the numerator.

Comment: Put another way, $x=sign(x)\sqrt {x^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is when you are shortening out $x$.  $x$ is negative, but the square root is positive.  Thus:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x}
&= \lim_{x \to-\infty} \frac{|x|\sqrt{1+4/x^2}}{-|x|} \\
&= \lim_{x \to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+4/x^2}}{-1} \\
&\to -1
\end{align}$$

where $x=-|x|$ in the denominator because $x < 0$.

---

Alternative way to see the limit is substituting $x= -y$:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{x}
&= \lim_{y \to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{(-y)^2+4}}{-y} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Typo : You wrote $n \to \infty$ instead of $x \to \infty$ in each limit.

Comment: @Digitallis:  huh? I cannot spot any typos.  It's all $\to-\infty$ except the last one which is correctly $\to\infty$.

Comment: You have a variable $n$ under your limit expression. Should be $x$. :-)

Comment: @user1046533: oops, I missed that, thanks. Fixed now.